# Deshabilitar avanzar en la barra de progreso de Exoplayer en Android

Tags: android, kotlin, progress

Estoy usando la librería de Exoplayer para cargar vídeos en mi aplicación, pero en ciertos vídeos quiero evitar que el usuario no pueda avanzar en la barra de progreso del vídeo, solamente retroceder, hasta ahora había conseguido algo añadiendo un listener a la DefaultTimeBar de esta forma:

```kotlin
var currentPosition: Long = 0
val exoPlayerProgressBar: DefaultTimeBar? = localPlayerView?.findViewById(
    R.id.exo_progress
) as? DefaultTimeBar
exoPlayerProgressBar?.addListener(object: TimeBar.OnScrubListener {
    override fun onScrubStart(timeBar: TimeBar, position: Long) {
        currentPosition = position
    }

    override fun onScrubMove(timeBar: TimeBar, position: Long) {
        if (currentPosition < position) {
            timeBar.setPosition(position)
            timeBar.setEnabled(false)
        }
    }

    override fun onScrubStop(timeBar: TimeBar, position: Long, canceled: Boolean) {
        timeBar.setEnabled(true)
    }
})
```

Pero no funciona bien del todo, creo que el listener tarda en ser llamado y el position del método onScrubStart no es exacto y aparte, aunque si que consigo deshabilitar que el usuario avance, no he conseguido hacer que si que pueda hacerlo si pulsa en un lugar de la barra. ¿Existe otra forma que no conozca?

Answer (score 0):

Debes usar `ExoPlayer.Listener` y sobreescribir `onPlaybackStateChanged()` para detectar el estado de reproducción del video (`Player.STATE_IDLE`, `Player.STATE_BUFFERING`, `Player.STATE_READY`, `Player.STATE_ENDED`), usa  `Player.STATE_READY` para ocultar la barra de progreso y `Player.STATE_BUFFERING` para mostrar la barra de progreso.

```
override fun onPlaybackStateChanged(playbackState: Int) {
    when (playbackState) {
        Player.STATE_ENDED -> {}
        Player.STATE_READY -> hideProgressBar() //*Hide progressbar!
        Player.STATE_BUFFERING -> showProgressBar() //*Show progressbar!
        Player.STATE_IDLE -> {}
    }
}
```

Revisa:

[Escucha de eventos de reproducción](https://exoplayer.dev/listening-to-player-events.html#listening-to-playback-events)